# Blend Behaviours - can you bind to their properties?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, attachedbehaviors

I am currently migrating a number of attached behaviours I have created to Blend Behaviours so that they support drag and drop within Expression Blend. I have noticed that authors of Blend behaviours tend to define the behaviour properties as dependency properties.

I have created a behaviour, `TiltBehaviour`, which exposes a public dependency property, `TiltFactor`,  of type double. Within Expression Blend I can set the value of this property, however, the option to add a "Data Binding ..." is grayed out:

[image: cannot bind to behaviour property]

I have also noticed that Behaviors extend `DependencyObject`, therefore they do not have a `DataContext` and therefore cannot inherit the `DataContext` of the element to which they are attached. This feels like a real weakness to me!

So, the bottom-line is, if I cannot set a binding to my behaviors dependency property in Blend, and it does not inherit a `DataContext`, why bother using dependency properties at all? I could just use CLR properties instead.

Comment: That's very strange, what version of Blend it is? I have no problem binding either element properties or DataContext properties to dependency properties of Behaviors with Blend 4 + Silverlight 4...

Comment: Dain, I have tried binding manually within Visual Studio, e.g. TiltFactor="{Binding}" this results in AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE, which often indicates that you are binding to a non-dependency property. Can you point to an example on the web of binding a property of a behaviour?

Comment: You have to bind to a concrete property of the right type: TiltFactor="{Binding TiltFactor}"

Comment: Dain ... it depends what your DataContext is, in my above example I was setting the DataContext of the element I was attaching to, to a double, e.g. Rectangle.DataContext = 10.0, therefore a binding of TiltFactor="{Binding}", without a property path is totally valid. Anyhow, I tried your suggestion TiltFactor="{Binding TiltFactor}", still no joy! .... perhaps it is a specific issue in VS / Silverlight for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Ah, sorry... Ran out of ideas, it works for me with SL4 even with implicitly inherited DataContext.

Comment: No problem - thanks for your help. I'll just have to give SL4 a try instead :-/ At least I know that it should work and that there is a perfectly good reason why these properties should be DPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** dain is correct you can still bind to the DataContext which is created artificially, how often have you seen people bind to a `SolidColorBrush.Color`? It also works even though SolidColorBrush inherits from DependencyObject and hence has no DataContext.

See [this blog post on the inheritance context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx).

The thing is that since the behaviours are attached, they do not appear in the logical tree and hence would not inherit a DataContext anyway.

Comment: +1 for the blog post on inheritance context. Why haven't I seen that before?! great stuff.

Comment: However ... they could be made to inherit the DataContext, as per this blog post: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/

Comment: It's weird that this information is either not in the documentation or very hard to find.

Answer (score 8):

Blend behaviors would be almost useless unless they supported binding!  I recreated your tilt behavior and it supports binding in Blend 4 with no problems so I don't know exactly where you went wrong.  Perhaps you can reproduce my simple example and then infer what's wrong with your setup.

Here's the (non-functional) tilt behavior with dependency property:

```
public class TiltBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public double TiltFactor
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TiltFactorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TiltFactorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TiltFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TiltFactor", typeof(double), typeof(TiltBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
}
```

Then just create a new window and drop the behavior onto the grid and Blend creates this:

```
<Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:TiltBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

and the Blend "Data Binding..." option is available in the properties tab.

I tested this with both WPF and Silverlight projects.  The built-in behaviors, triggers and actions all support binding by virtue of using being dependency properties and all the Blend samples use binding heavily and so this **has** to work.

In fact you can just drop a built-in behavior like `FluidMoveBehavior` onto your grid and check that `Duration`, which is a dependency property, supports binding.  If that doesn't work, I have **no** idea what's going on!

---

Let's consider then how binding works for these strange beasts called behaviors.

As WPF or Silverlight programmers we are very familiar with binding for things like `FrameworkElement`.  It has a property called `DataContext` that we can manipulate to control the default binding source and that property is inherited by nested elements when we **don't** override it.

But behaviors (and triggers and actions) are **not** of type `FrameworkElement`.  They are ultimately derived from `DependencyObject`, as we might expect.  But while we can using binding on **any** class derived from `DependencyObject`, our familiar `DataContext` is missing at this low-level and so the binding has to supply the source.  **That's** not very convenient.

So behaviors are derived (on WPF anyway) from `Animatable` and `Animatable` is derived from `Freezable`.  The `Freezable` class is where the simplicity of dependency objects intersects with the complexity of framework elements.  The `Freezable` class is also the base class for more familiar things like brushes and image sources.  These classes don't need the full complexity of a framework element, but they want to participate, in a **limited way** with the elements that they are associated with.

Through a complicated magical process, `Freezable` instances acquire an inheritance context: the framework element they are most closely associated with, and when a default binding is used (one without a source), the `Freezable` uses the `DataContext` of it's associated element instead.

In fact as you learn about behaviors the `AssociatedObject` is a central concept; for a behavior it is the thing that the behavior is attached to.  But the important point is that all `Freezable` objects can use the `DataContext` of their `AssociatedObject` by proxy.

All this magic is what [Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/) calls the:

- [Hillberg Freezable Trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/21/model-see_2c00_-model-do.aspx)

And so all this leads up to saying that due to the *Hillberg Freezable Trick*, Blend behaviors support binding using the data context of their associated element as the default source.  As a result, bindings for behaviors seem to "just work" without any effort on our part.  Behaviors are a thousand times more useful because of this.